# When applying for a multi-entry Schengen visa, do you have to provide itineraries for every single future trip?

Tags: visas, schengen, spain, multiple-entry, uk-residents

I am planning to apply for a Schengen Visa in the near future through the Spanish Embassy in London. I am a Turkish citizen who studies in the UK, hence a UK resident (but not a citizen). I was just wondering, when I am applying for a Multi-Visit visa, do I need to prove every single travel that I intend to do with flight reservations, hotel bookings etc. I will be staying in Spain for 4 days and I have all relevant documents for that, however, I plan on visiting Amsterdam and/or Paris in the future with my flatmates, the dates of which are unplanned as of now.

For reference, my mother who lives and works in Turkey, recently got a Multi-Entry Schengen Visa for 1 year even though she only had to prove her 3 days travel to Greece.

Comment: `do I need to prove every single travel that I intend to do with flight reservations, hotel bookings etc.` You do it only the first time while applying for the visa and every time you apply for a visa.

Comment: @DumbCoder you also need to be prepared to do it every time you enter the Schengen area.

Comment: @DumbCoder So when I am applying now, I would only prove my travel to Spain and state in my cover letter, fill in the form accordingly that I want as long as possible and indeed multi-visit type?

Comment: @phoog Yeah that is fair. I would have everything on me or in my email anyway so that would be fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you only have to provide the itinerary for your first trip, as well as a justification for why you need a multi-entry visa. E.g. here's what the [Czech consulate in Teheran](http://www.mzv.cz/teheran/en/visa_and_consular_information/basic_schengen_visa_information_2.html) says about multi-entry visas:

> Multiple-entry visas may be issued with a period of validity between six months and five years, where the following conditions are met:
>
> (a)  The applicant proves the need or justifies the intention to travel frequently and/or regularly, in particular due to his occupational or family status, such as business persons, civil servants engaged in regular official contacts with Member States, and EU institutions, representatives of civil society organisations travelling for the purpose of educational training, seminars and conferences, family members of citizens of the Union, family members of third-country nationals legally residing in Member States and seafarers; and
>
> (b)  The applicant proves his integrity and reliability, in particular the lawful use of previous uniform visas or visas with limited territorial validity, his economic situation in the country of origin and his genuine intention to leave the territory of the Member States before the expiry of the visa applied for.

Otherwise the requirements for applying for a multi-entry visa are exactly the same.

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev have you held Schengen visas before? Normally they issue an open ended multiple entry visa only if you have a good history.

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev Contact the consulate immediately, because those two trips together require 13 days of visa validity.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Is there any reliable source I can rely upon? A clear official statement of how days are calculated for my visa? Without it I can't even make a claim to them.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I think your comment belongs to a different question